# How to filter a row if the value contains in list in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to filter a spark dataframe using list, for example

```
var lisst=List(1,2,34)
df.filter(col("id).isin(lisst))
```

give the error

```
Unsupported literal type classscala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon 
List(1,2,34)
```

I tried with `Seq` and `Set` and get same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `isin` function as below

```
var lisst=List(1,2,34)
 df.filter(col("id").isin(lisst :_*))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, is there something like - "is NOT in"?

Comment: You can simply use not() function. or ! which inverse the result

Comment: So, for the above example, something like:
`df.filter(!col("id").isin(lisst :_*))` ?

Answer (score 0):

you've got to expand the list :)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

var lisst=List(1,2,34)
df.filter(col("id).isin(lisst:_*)).show()
```